# How would I assign each list item a sequential ID in Javascript? (in an html document by the way)

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the section which is confusing me:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //declaring veriables
    var inputField = document.getElementById("input");
    var addBtn = document.getElementById("addBtn");
    var html = "";
    var x = 0;

    addBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
        var text = inputField.value;
        addToList(text);
    })
    //adds items to list
    function addToList(text){

         html += "<li id=(x+=1)><h4><input type='checkbox' id=(x+=1) onclick= 'clearspecifieditems()'>"+text+"</h4></li>";
        document.getElementById("myList").innerHTML = html;
        inputField.value = "";
    }
    //clears items

    function clearspecifieditems(itemid)
    {
        //delete selected item
    };
```

So the goal here is to create a to-do list (I'm new to coding). The `addToList(text)` function is supposed to create a new list item and assign a sequential ID to it. However, I cannot seem to figure out how to have it generate the ID. In addition, `clearspecifieditems(itemid)` is supposed to get the IDs of all the list items that are checked, and clear all of them.

Comment: You never want  to remove any insert ?

Comment: You don't need an unique `id` for that, just do `onclick='clearspecifieditems(this)'` and then in your function you do `itemid.remove();`. You might want to rename `itemid` to e.g. `item` though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of your question either use string concatenation similar to how you added the `text` variable...

```
function addToList(text) {
  const id = x + 1;
  html += '<li id="' + id + '"><h4><input type="checkbox" id="' + id + '">' + text + '</h4></li>';
  // ..
}
```

...or use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
function addToList(text) {
  const id = x + 1;
  html += `<li id="${id}"><h4><input type="checkbox" id="${id}" />${text}</h4></li>`;
  // ..
}
```

**HOWEVER**, for the second part, how to clear checked boxes:

I purposely left the `onclick` out of the above code because it sounds as if you need a separate button to clear the checkboxes:

```js
// Grab the button and add an click listener to it
// to call `clearSpecifiedItems` 
const button = document.querySelector('.clear');
button.addEventListener('click', clearSpecifiedItems, false);

function clearSpecifiedItems() {

  // Select all the checked checkboxes using their class
  const selected = document.querySelectorAll('.test:checked');

  // Set their checked property to false (or null)
  selected.forEach(input => input.checked = false);
}
```

```html
<input class="test" type="checkbox" />
<input class="test" type="checkbox" />
<input class="test" type="checkbox" />
<input class="test" type="checkbox" />

<button class="clear">Clear</button>
```

Notice that *none of these inputs have IDs*. I've used a class to pick up the elements instead. So unless you're using the ids for anything else it makes the first part of your code redundant. Just use a CSS selector to grab the elements you need and then process them. No IDs required!

Answer (score 1):

Just use **[string interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)** to reference the `x` variable and increment it by one every time you add a new item as follows:

```js
    
    /* JavaScript */
    var inputField = document.getElementById("input");
    var addBtn = document.getElementById("addBtn");
    var output = document.getElementById("output");
    var html = "";
    var x = 0;
    
    function addToList(text) {        
         output.innerHTML += `<li id=id${x}><h4><input type='checkbox' id=${x}>This list item has an id: id${x}"</h4></li>`;
         inputField.value = "";
         x++;
    }
        
    addBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
        var text = inputField.value;
        addToList(text);
    })
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<input type="text" id="input" />
<button id="addBtn">Add Items</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

And for removing checked elements, simply add another button, say `removeBtn` and then add a click listener to the button that invokes the `clearspecifieditems()`.

Inside the function, assign a variable to a list of all the checkboxes, loop through the variable using `forEach` and remove any checkbox that is not checked like this:

```js
    function clearspecifieditems() {
     var check = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="id"]');
      check.forEach(checkBox => {
          if(checkBox.children[0].children[0].checked){
              checkBox.remove();
          }
      });
    }
    
    removeBtn.addEventListener('click', clearspecifieditems);
```

```css
#output {list-style: none;}
```

```html
/* <input type="text" id="input" />
<button id="addBtn">Add Items</button> */

<ul id="output">
  <li id="id0"><h4><input type="checkbox" id="input0">This list item has an id: id0"</h4></li>
  <li id="id1"><h4><input type="checkbox" id="input1">This list item has an id: id1"</h4></li>
  <li id="id2"><h4><input type="checkbox" id="input2">This list item has an id: id2"</h4></li>
  <li id="id3"><h4><input type="checkbox" id="input3">This list item has an id: id3"</h4></li>
</ul>
<hr>
<button id="removeBtn">Remove</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see what you're going for. You are almost there. Just a little bit of syntactical error, and a bit of a logical one.

You see, when you increment `x` two times, You will have a different id for the `<li>` and the `<input>`. What I suggest is you increment the x beforehand and then use it.

You can do it like this:

```
function addToList(text){
  x++;
  html += "<li id="+ x +"><h4><input type='checkbox' id="+ x +" onclick= 'clearspecifieditems()'>"+text+"</h4></li>";
  document.getElementById("myList").innerHTML = html;
  inputField.value = "";
}
```

or this (ES6)

```
function addToList(text){
  x++;
  html += `<li id=${x}><h4><input type='checkbox' id=${x} onclick= 'clearspecifieditems()'>${text}</h4></li>`;
  document.getElementById("myList").innerHTML = html;
  inputField.value = "";
}
```

Is it absolutely necessary that you must only increment? Can the ID's be truly unique? I suggest you use [UUID](https://gist.github.com/jed/982883) in that case

---

Your second question is how to make `clearspecifieditems` work. Here's what you can do. You can pass the context, or simply the checkbox that was clicked and then get it's ID easily..

So you would define your function something like this:

```
function clearspecifieditems(element){
  //delete selected item
  console.log(element.id); // this would give you the ID of the selected checkbox and then you can do whatever with it
};
```

and slightly modify your function call on the click event

```
html += "<li id="+ x +"><h4><input type='checkbox' id="+ x +" onclick= 'clearspecifieditems(this)'>"+text+"</h4></li>";
```

Note this `this` part.

More more information, [See this](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-this-event-handlers/)

Answer (score 0):

You're sending X as 1. You should do like this :

```js
var input = document.getElementById("input");
var div = document.getElementById("div");
var button = document.getElementById("addbutton");
var id = 0;

button.onclick = function() { 
   text = input.value;
   addtask(text)
}

function addtask(text) { 

   var element = document.createElement("li");  
   element.setAttribute("id", id)
   var deleteE = document.createElement("input");
   deleteE.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
   deleteE.setAttribute("onclick", "deleteX(" + id + ")");
   
   var node = document.createTextNode(text);
   
   element.appendChild(deleteE);
   element.appendChild(node);
   div.appendChild(element);
   
   id += 1;
}

function deleteX(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

```html
<input id="input"> <button id="addbutton"> add </button>

<div id="div"></br> </div>
```